# Computing $f \circ g$ and $g \circ f$ for functions by cases

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, problem-solving, function-and-relation-composition

I want to confirm my solution for the following problem from Ethan D. Bloch’s *Proofs and Fundamentals*.

**Problem:** Let $f,g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be real functions of a real variable given by

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1-2x, & \text{if} & 0 \leq x \\ |x|, & \text{if} & x < 0 \end{cases}, \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R} \quad \text{and}$$

$$g(x) = \begin{cases} 3x, & \text{if} & 0 \leq x \\
x-1, & \text{if} & x < 0 \end{cases}, \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}.$$

Find $f \circ g$ and $g \circ f$.

**Solution:** We start with $f \circ g$. First, we observe that $0 \leq g(x)$, for all $x \in [0, \infty)$. So, $(f \circ g) (x) = 1-6x$, for all $x \in [0,\infty)$. Next, we observe that $g(x) < 0$ for all $x \in (-\infty,0)$. Hence, $(f \circ g)(x) = |x-1|$, for all $x \in (-\infty,0)$.

Then, we compute $g \circ f$. Following the same argument, we see that $0 \leq f(x)$, for all $x \in (-\infty,\frac{1}{2}]$. So, we have that $(g \circ f)(x) = 3-6x$, for all $x \in (-\infty,\frac{1}{2}]$. Next, we observe that $f(x) < 0$, for all $x \in (\frac{1}{2},\infty)$. Hence, we have that $(g \circ f)(x)=|x|-1$, for all $x \in (\frac{1}{2},\infty)$.

Therefore, we have that $f \circ g, g \circ f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are defined by

$$
(f \circ g)(x) = \begin{cases} 1-6x, & \text{if} & 0 \leq x \\
|x-1|, & \text{if} & x<0\end{cases}, \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R} \quad \text{and}
$$

$$
(g \circ f)(x) = \begin{cases} 3-6x, & \text{if} & x \leq \frac{1}{2} \\
|x|-1, & \text{if} & \frac{1}{2} < x \end{cases}, \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}.
$$

**My question:**

1. Is this enough and correct?
2. Is there any online calculator (or the like) that compute this expressions?

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: Looks good to me and is enough

Comment: $g\circ f$ is wrong.

Comment: The reason that your simple approach to $f\circ g$ works is that $g(x)\geq 0$ iff $x\geq0.$

Comment: What is the mistake here?

Comment: Try $g(f(1)).$ You get $f(1)=-1,$ so $g(f(1))=-2.$ You have $g\circ f(1)=|1|-1=0.$ @AirMike

Comment: You only get $3-6x$ for $0\leq x\leq 1/2$

Comment: Basically, there should be three cases for $x$, (1) $x<0$, (2) $0\leq x\leq 1/2,$ and (3) $x>1/2.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews thank you for your observation, I’m going to work on that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the feedback in the comments, I came with the following solution that a I believe to be the right one. So, we have that $f \circ g, g \circ f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, defined by

$$
(f \circ g)(x)= \begin{cases} 1-6x, & \text{if} & 0 \leq x \\
|x-1|, & \text{if} & x < 0 \end{cases}, \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R} \quad \text{and}
$$

$$
(g \circ f)(x)= \begin{cases} 3|x|, & \text{if} & x < 0 \\
3-6x, & \text{if} & 0 \leq x \leq \frac{1}{2} \\
-2x, & \text{if} & \frac{1}{2} < x \end{cases}, \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}.
$$

The problem with the initial solution was that I didn’t observe that, for $x \in (-\infty, \frac{1}{2}]$, the function $f$ is different when $x<0$ and $0 \leq x$.